# How to print json console.log data in browser for use with api

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, xml-parsing

Okay... I would like to create an api but i cant seem to output the data, i have parsed it from an xml file and can console.log the necessary data but when i want to output the data to the browser i just get an empty array any suggestions?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const xmlParser = require("xml2json")

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
        
        let xmin = req.query.xmin;
        let xmax = req.query.xmax;
        let ymin = -Math.abs(req.query.ymin);
        let ymax = -Math.abs(req.query.ymax);
        
        

        const foodRatings = fs.readFile( "./FHRS433en-GB.xml", function(err, data) {
            const xmlObj = xmlParser.toJson(data, {reversible: true, object: true})
            const estDetail = xmlObj["FHRSEstablishment"]['EstablishmentCollection']['EstablishmentDetail']
            
            
            for (let i=0;i < estDetail.length;i++) {
                let latitude = estDetail[i]["Geocode"]["Latitude"]
                let longitude = estDetail[i]["Geocode"]["Longitude"]
                if ((typeof latitude !== "undefined") && (typeof longitude !== "undefined")) {
                        if ((latitude['$t'] >= xmin && latitude['$t'] <= xmax) && (longitude['$t'] >= ymin && longitude['$t'] <= ymax)) {
                            // jsonData += estDetail[i];
                            let jsonData = [];
                            var config = JSON.parse(estDetail[i]);
                            jsonData.push(config);
                            console.log(jsonData);
                            res.json(jsonData);
                        } 
                } 
            }
        })
});
```

When i see people outputting the data online they have the json data in an object which links directly to the string not a file, i dont know how i would go about extracting the data from the file passing it into an empty array then which i can call the data using res.json(jsonData)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u try to

```
return res.json(data)
```

I see you are in a for loop, so probably you want to do that outside of it

Comment: i found out what i was doing wrong i used return res.json(jsonData) just i made a silly mistake and didnt add the parameters to the get request  Thank you a lot though!!